# pro tools surround panner

Tags: pro-tools, 5.1, surround-sound, panning, avid

I'm finally approaching doing my first 5.1 mix. I'm doing this in pro tools 10 HD. My only other experience of 5.1 has been in Logic and Nuendo.

Does pro tools have a built in surround panner? At present all I have is a small box with a green dot in the mix lane. This does the trick but in other programs there is a lot more available, perhaps even a separate pop up window? I just can't seem to find it or have it on this system.

1) Is there something I've missed and hasn't been installed?

2) Have they removed this in typical AVID fashion and do I need to purchase a 3rd party plugin such as maggot's Spanner or Iosono Anymix?

Thanks

Comment: Only in ProTools HD, correct?

Answer (score 1):

ProTools does have a built in surround panner, it has for a long time.
Have you read the manual at all?  It sounds like you already have a bias against ProTools without having actually used it all based on your 2nd question.
You just have to have the 5.1 mixer installed and surround panning will work.
Did you click on the small fader next to the volume number?
Is your track routed to the correct type of output buss?

Comment: Not biased at all, Protools is what I use everyday, I just have never done a 5.1 mix on it. Like I said this is the first time I'm tackling 5.1 seriously.

I will double check the manual and double check clicking said faders. I have clicked all over it though. It should be installed, pro tools was fully installed, and it is all routed right. The surround panning works... I just can't see an external pop up window for it wherever I click.

Comment: It looks like this

Comment: It looks like this  http://designingsound.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/001.png  then you just click on the fader icon next to the output assignment  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Protools9screen.png

Comment: It's always worked well for me and can write automation from the panning window.  I didn't mean an insult by my ProTools Bias comment, you had just said "2) Have they removed this in typical AVID fashion and do I need..."  - as far as I can remember AVID has never removed anything from ProTools that was in a previous version, again no insult intended.

Comment: No insult taken honestly. I should've read the manual, I would've skimmed it and missed it though I bet. Thanks again!